# During at the beginning or at the end of the sentence?

Tags: word-usage

Which of these sentences are correct? Or both correct? 
1. During stages 1 and 2 l sleep lightly. 
2. I sleep lightly during stages 1 and 2.

Comment: What makes you think either is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Both versions are grammatically correct; the arrangement of the sentence depends on what you wish to accentuate.  If you are discussing the various stages of sleep and reporting what you experience in each, the first sentence seems most appropriate.  If you are discussing the depth of sleep (or lack thereof), you may want to use the second sentence.